# Username and password field get values from older project

Tags: php

I started to learn `php` programming and I am using xampp as a local server.

My `.htdocs` file is full with different projects and experiments.

My problem is that every time I am creating a Login form and I test my page, it automatically sets a value (a username and password).

How can I avoid it or find the source to this problem? I am afraid I have done something that might be very problematic if it is in production.

Comment: It's usually because you've clicked 'remember username/password'. Clear your browser cache/cookies and then reload. Or, call your inputs something else eg `name='username'` to `name='new_username'` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Are you sure this doesnt come from your browser? Did you store access credentials in there?

Comment: It's nor a problem of the browser nor of the code. As say BeatAlex clean the browser cache/cookies. A trick can be use the inprivate browsing, that didn't read data from cache or cookies. It's a good way for testing your applications and not run into previous data/errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "problem" from your browser. You have clicked "Save this login data". And all your projects under the same host... `http://localhost/project-1/`, `http://localhost/project-2/`

delete the autofill data from your browser...

happy coding, dude ;-)